# How to link multiple scripts?

Tags: python, function

I would like to separate my functions into different files like I do with c++ (a driver file and a file for different categories of functions that I end up linking together upon compilation).

Let's suppose I want to create a simple 'driver' file which launches the main program and a 'function' file which includes simple functions which are called by the driver and other functions within the 'function' file.

How should I do this? Since python is not compiled, how do I link files together?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can `import` modules. Simply create different python files and import them at the start of your script.

For example I got this `function.py` file :

```
def func(a, b):
    return a+b
```

And this `main.py` file:

```
import function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ans = function.func(2, 3)
    print(ans)
```

And that is it! This is the official [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) on importing modules.

Comment: In my case when I make print ans, it prints None. I don't know why :( Can anyone help me??

Comment: @ePascoal Are you sure you are "returning" a+b in func?

Comment: Amazing! Before I saw this I always used sockets!

Comment: @Luke I would love to see how you do that with sockets.

Comment: Trust me, it is not that disguting, but makes things a bit more complex sometimes. Basically you get the two files to connect and talk. Listen when it needs to.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I was wondering if there was any performance hit in linking multiple scripts together. For example, if I'm writing a complex model and each script is calling functions from other scripts, would it be more efficient to have all the functions in one big mega-file? Or is there no performance hit when the program is compiled?

Comment: @Yoshi Each call to `module.function` requires two checks in a dictionary: one to find the module in the local variables and one to find the function in the module's variables. You could use the `from module import function` to reduce this impact. However, you have to call a function really often for this to be measurable. Readability should be your first concern here. Calling functions from two separate modules should not impact your performance differently as the same kind of lookup is done for all modules. The itertools mention this optimization on the very last line of the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

You can import any Python file simply by typing:

```
import filename
```

But in this case you have to type the file name each time you want to use it. For example, you have to use `filename.foo` to use the specific function `foo` inside that file. However, you can also do the following:

```
from function import *
```

In this case all you have to do is to directly type your commands without `filename`.

A clear example:

If you are working with the Python turtle by using `import turtle` then each time you have to type `turtle.foo`. For example: `turtle.forward(90)`, `turtle.left(90)`, `turtle.up()`.

But if you use `from turtle import *` then you can do the same commands without `turtle`. For example: `forward(90)`, `left(90)`, `up()`.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of driver.py, write:

```
import functions
```

This gives you access to attributes defined in functions.py, referenced like so:

```
functions.foo
functions.bar(args)
...
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are variables available also?