# python program wraparound

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following program statement (program1.py)

I have a program 1:

```
try:

except:
```

I have another program 2 (program2.py):

```
def something: 
      print hello
```

is there a way when program 1 is imported into program 2 , that program 1 wraps around program 2, so the program should be

```
try:
   def something: 
          print hello    # all program 2 components

except:
```

I am confused on how to do this and any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: [Here're some pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would suggest going about this is with a decorator:

```
def tryit(fn):
    def wraps(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
    return wraps

def doStuff(x, y):
    return x / y

@tryit
def main(arg1, arg2):
    print doStuff(arg1, arg2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(1, 10.0)
    main(100, 0)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0.1
integer division or modulo by zero
```

Your logic might need to be reworked, but I think it would be worth it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In program1.py, you need to call the `something` function. Thereby, it would wrap the new function (by function call) into try-except block. I suggest, you understand inter-module program flow handling from basic information on net. You must not view it as simple parse but as a function call.

HTH.

Below links will help you to understand.
[Modules in python and integration.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)
[Similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028036/how-to-link-multiple-python-scripts).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a import

program1.py:

```
from program2 import something
try:
    something()
exception:
    # Some more code
```

program2.py:

```
def something:
    print 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: Your python is syntactically invalid

Answer (score 0):

`program2.py`:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tryer():
    try:
        yield  # code within with statement runs here
    except:
        print "Failed!
```

`program1.py`:

```
from program2 import tryer

with tryer():
    print 'Hello, World!'
```